# Creating a dynamic row file upload and drop down option in system config

Tags: magento2.2.2, system-config, dynamic-rows

I've checked the example here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

Which add text inputs, But how to add other types of input such as drop down and file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully answered the question but it helps to point in the right direction;

Under Class: `Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray` You can overwrite on you custom class the method responsible to rendering the html input:look for `renderCellTemplate` Method:

As a test I have overwritten by simply changing from: `type="text"` to: `type="checkbox"` and The result is: [image]

All it need to do is add html `<select>` and `<option>` html and that should do.

**UPDATE:** I've made use of `renderer` here is an example from Braintree module.

```
/**
     * Returns renderer for country element
     *
     * @return Countries
     */
    protected function getCountryRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->countryRenderer) {
            $this->countryRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                Countries::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->countryRenderer;
    }
```

The above is rendering the countries drop down but I am loading the categories. finale look like this:
[image]
Best!